# Multiple consumer groups in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

i am new to kafka , my question is how to create multiple consumer groups with multiple consumer instances and assign that consumer instances to consume from specific broker or partition ? For eg: i have to implement as shown in this example image[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consumer groups relate to the high level consumer API while the ability to choose broker or partition to consume from relates to the simple consumer API.

The high level API will do rebalancing among consumers in a group automatically for you but it will consume all partitions for a given topic.

If you want to consume only from specific partitions within a topic, you need to use the simple consumer API and you'll have to deal with partition assignment yourself. There is an example of how to do this in the [Kafka wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example).